# Why does xamarin not run the event Navigating during pushModalAsync, but MAUI does?

Tags: c#, xamarin, maui

I am migrating from xamarin to maui, but I noticed that xamarin doesn't run the navigating event, but maui does

## **For Example**

I first run this(both xamarin and maui):

```
private async Task UpdateStock()
{
    IsBusy = true;
    InputNumberViewModel model = new InputNumberViewModel();
    model.Text = "Vul de nieuwe voorraad in";
    model.Number = product.Current.Stock;
    InputNumberPage p = new InputNumberPage(model);
    p.Disappearing += async (s, e) =>
    {
        if (!model.IsCancelled)
        {
            IsUpdatingStock = true;
            product.Current.Stock = model.Number;
            string error = await UpdateProduct();
            IsUpdatingStock = false;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(error))
            {
                await Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Opslaan is niet gelukt", error, "OK");
            }
            else
            {
                StockUpdatedFlag.Raise();
            }
        }
        IsBusy = false;
    };
    await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(p, true);
    p.FocusEntry();
}
```

### **Xamarin**

When it goes through `await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(p, true);`
it only runs OnDissapearing

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    //Shell.Current.Navigating -= OnNavigating;
    App.Instance.CodeScanned -= OnBarcodeScanned;
}
private void OnNavigating(object sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.viewModel != null && this.viewModel.IsBusy)
        e.Cancel();
}
```

### **MAUI**

When it goes through `await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(p, true);`
it runs OnNavigating first and then(if OnNavigating didn't cancel) OnDisappearing.

```
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    base.OnDisappearing();
    Shell.Current.Navigating -= OnNavigating;
    App.Instance.CodeScanned -= OnBarcodeScanned;
}
private void OnNavigating(object sender, ShellNavigatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.viewModel != null && this.viewModel.IsBusy)
        e.Cancel();
}
```

The problem is that when MAUI goes through OnNavigating it cancels the PushModalAsync since it's still busy

Ofcourse it is fixable by setting the IsBusy boolean to false before it goes through PushModalAsync

```
IsBusy = false;
await Shell.Current.Navigation.PushModalAsync(p, true);
```

But I want to know why xamarin doesn't run the Navigating event and MAUI does.

Comment: It was probably a decision made by the Xamarin team, that MAUI team decided to change, honestly it makes sense to call the event when ModalPage is added too since it is "Navigating"